# C++ MySQL prepareStatement

Tags: c++, mysql

```
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;
    //connect

    pstmt = con->prepareStatement("UPDATE table_people SET name=?, age=?");

    pstmt->setString(1, s);

    pstmt->setInt(2, age());
    pstmt->execute();
```

`std::string s` is the input string, the column `name` is `VARCHAR` and `age` is `INT`

The code updates all the rows, as expected. `age` is correct but the `name` is not updated correctly and weird symbols are saved. Why, please?

Comment: What is the exact type of "s"? Is it `std::string?`

Comment: it's `std::string`, yes

Comment: What type is setString expecting for its second parameter? Does your `s` variable live until after execute() is called or is it destroyed before then?

Comment: `setString expects sql::SQLString` type. My variable lives after execute is called.

Comment: Did you try `pstmt->setString(1, s.c_str());` just to see if passing a C-string gives the same result?

Comment: @Dan Nissenbaum: works!!! How?

Comment: Is the `sql::SQLString` parameter for `setString` passed by reference or by value? Also how does the `std::string` get converted to `sql::SQLString`? Have a look at this question as this may be related to your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853074/sqlsqlstring-behavior

Comment: If I recall from using the MySQL C++ library in the past - this library does not actually define functions that accept type `std::string`, so as not to 'force' users to include "unnecessary" headers (i.e., `#include <string>`); somehow the implicit conversion from `std::string` to `sql::SQLString` is not working as you'd expect.  (I never looked into what it was really doing.)

Comment: I see... I expected the MySQL c++ connector to be pretty well know, but seems like very few are using it and MySQL is mainly used with PHP... Maybe MySQL is not great with C++? Anyway, thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: To the contrary - the C++ API is very important, because it uses the direct socket connection to MySQL that is used internally by the MySQL daemon.  Internally, I suspect the PHP implementation also uses either the C++ or the analogous C library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment seems to be correct, I'll post it as an answer :)

Use

```
pstmt->setString(1, s.c_str());
```

(namely, pass an actual C-style string, not a `std::string`).

I *think* I know the explanation for why this resolves the issue, but since I'm not 100% certain about the explanation, please see my comment beneath the question for my thought about why it works.