# CString to std::string or sql::SQLString conversion - C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, type-conversion, c-strings

I'm trying to convert a CString variable coming from a `CComboBox` to a `std::string` or `sql::SQLString` one for set it in a SQL query (using Mysql Connector C++).So, here my code:

```
CComboBox *pComboRule = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(ID_EDIT_RULE);
CComboBox *pComboAg1 = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(ID_EDIT_AG1);
CComboBox *pComboAg2 = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(ID_EDIT_AG2);
CComboBox *pComboAg3 = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(ID_EDIT_AG3);

CString &AG1 = CString(_T("A string"));
CString &AG2 = CString(_T("A string"));
CString &AG3 = CString(_T("A string"));
CString str;

pComboAg1->GetLBText(pComboAg1->GetCurSel(), AG1);
pComboAg2->GetLBText(pComboAg2->GetCurSel(), AG2);
pComboAg3->GetLBText(pComboAg3->GetCurSel(), AG3);


try {

    std::string s = CStringA(AG1);

    sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT `nAccessIdn` FROM `base`.`tb_table` WHERE `field` IN (?, ?, ?) LIMIT 3");
    pstmt->setString(1, s);
    pstmt->setString(2, s);
    pstmt->setString(3, s);
    sql::ResultSet *res = pstmt->executeQuery();

    if (res->rowsCount() != 0) {

        while (res->next())
        {

            str.Format(_T("AG : %s\r\n"), res->getString(1));
            OutputDebugString(str);

        }

    }

}
catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
    CString itemString;
    itemString.Format(_T("SQLException %s"), CString(e.what()));
    MessageBox(itemString, _T("Failed Logon Attempt"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}
```

I already try a lot of thing like

```
std::string s((LPCTSTR)AG1);
```

OR

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR>
```

OR

```
std::string std(somStr, someStr.GetLength());
```

OR

```
CT2A(cst.GetString());
```

OR

```
char* myStr = "This is a C string!";
std::string myCppString = myStr;
```

etc...

Does anyone know a way to succeed ?

DETAILS :

Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition - Unicode project - Runtime Library : /MDd

Thanks a lot for your help :)

EDIT : Newbie in C++, code updated.

Comment: You tried - and what's wrong?

Comment: No solution works...

Comment: And that means?

Comment: because it's a wide string build?

Comment: I often have bad_alloc exceptions but I don't understand why because when i want to use a pointer, some functions or conversions didn't work. It's logical, but i'm new in C++ and i don't see  how to deal with it ...

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853074/sqlsqlstring-behavior)? Try building the mysql library from source. But better yet, try the unencumbered [mariadb](https://launchpad.net/mariadb++) connector.

Comment: why do you use `CStringA` in this era?

Comment: You changed question's body. What are you trying to do here: `CString &AG1 = CString(_T("A string"));`?

Comment: LưuVĩnhPhúc & ZDF, just tests for proposed answers...

Answer (score 2):

```
CString &AG1 = CString(_T("A string"));
pComboAg1->GetLBText(pComboAg1->GetCurSel(), AG1);
```

This is wrong in so many ways. `AG1` is a pointer to some fixed data and you are setting `AG1` with something else.

Just use:

```
CString AG1;
pComboAg1->GetLBText(pComboAg1->GetCurSel(), AG1);
```

Your SQL data is expected to be UTF-8. If you are creating a new MFC program then `UNICODE` option is enabled by default (UTF-16).

Getting data from database:

```
std::string str;
//get str from databases
CStringW atl = CA2W(str.c_str(), CP_UTF8);
combobox.AddString(atl);
```

Sending data to databse:

```
CString AG1;
combobox.GetLBText(0, AG1);
std::string str = CW2A(AG1, CP_UTF8);
...
```

In rare cases the data could be ANSI, in that case remove the `CP_UTF8` flag.

Answer (score 1):

**CString to std::string**

```
CString cstr = L"Hello";
std::string str = std::string(CStringA(cstr));
```

**CString to sql::SQLString**

```
CString cstr = L"Hello";
std::string str = std::string(CStringA(cstr));
sql::SQLString sqstr = sql::SQLString(str.c_str());
```